# Define global variable for AWS credentials in build.gradle?

Tags: gradle, amazon-s3, groovy, build.gradle, credentials

I'm trying to parse the file `~/.aws/credentials` with specific user so that the selected `user credentials` can be pass to aws credentias. I have create this very simple script to the the job :

```
// there is a function `getProfile` defined before this and return map value
ext.profileAWSAccess = getProfile("gujarat")['accessKey']
ext.profileAWSSecret = getProfile("gujarat")['secretKey']

println(getProfile("gujarat"))

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }

        maven {
            url "${internal_s3_url1}"
            credentials(AwsCredentials) {
                accessKey profileAWSAccess
                secretKey profileAWSSecret
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These are the things that I have tried :

- pass variable using `"${profielAWSAccess}"`
- pass variable using `"profileAWSAccess"`
- using `profileAWSAccess` instead `ext.profileAWSAccess` in declared variable

none above are working and I got this error :

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'bootcamp'.
> Could not get unknown property 'profileAWSAccess' for object of type org.gradle.internal.credentials.DefaultAwsCr
edentials_Decorated.
```

Where did I go wrong ?

And why my `profileAWSAccess` is type of `ype org.gradle.internal.credentials.DefaultAwsCr
edentials_Decorated` ?

any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: The `buildscript` block is a special block that will always be executed before anything else in your build script. This is the reason why the extra properties don't exist at this point. Simply move the extra properties and your method to the `buildscript` block.

Comment: @lu.koerfer thank you for this it helps.